# How to create and execute a function using the Apps Script API

Tags: ruby, google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform, google-apps-script-api

I created a script following "[Ruby Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/quickstart/ruby)"  but I can't run it with the API.

I know that I should publish it as API executable. To do that I need to  switch the script project to use a "[standard GCP project](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/cloud-platform-projects#switching_to_a_different_standard_gcp_project)"  and I couldn't find how to do it from the API.

If I switch it manually it works. When I execute the code below I get this error:

```
> 403, PERMISSION_DENIED: The caller does not have permission
```

This is the code:

```
def create_and_execute
  # Initialize the API
  service = Google::Apis::ScriptV1::ScriptService.new
  service.client_options.application_name = APPLICATION_NAME
  service.authorization = authorize

  # Make the API request.
  request = Google::Apis::ScriptV1::CreateProjectRequest.new(
  title: "My Script3"
  )
  resp = service.create_project request

  script_id = resp.script_id
  content = Google::Apis::ScriptV1::Content.new(
  files:     [
    Google::Apis::ScriptV1::File.new(
    name:   "hello",
    type:   "SERVER_JS",
    source: "function helloWorld() {\n  console.log('Hello, world!');\n}"
    ),
    Google::Apis::ScriptV1::File.new(
    name:   "appsscript",
    type:   "JSON",
    source: "{\"timeZone\":\"America/Los_Angeles\",\"exceptionLogging\":\"CLOUD\",\"executionApi\":{\"access\":\"ANYONE\"}}"
    )
],
script_id: script_id
)

service.update_project_content(script_id, content)    
service.create_project_version(script_id,Google::Apis::ScriptV1::Version.new(script_id: script_id))
service.create_project_deployment(script_id,Google::Apis::ScriptV1::DeploymentConfig.new(script_id: script_id,version_number: 1))
service.run_script(script_id, Google::Apis::ScriptV1::ExecutionRequest.new(function: 'helloWorld', dev_mode: true))
  end
```

Comment: Welcome. The instruction you are looking for are in https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api

Comment: Don't think you can switch from the api.

Comment: I would like to confirm the method for replicating your error message. So can I ask you about the detail flow that you did for using the Apps Script API?

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry to inform you that this operation is not possible. You need to use a standard browser interface (read as *not an API*) to switch a GCP project as described [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/cloud-platform-projects#switching_to_a_different_standard_gcp_project). On [this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/how-tos/enable#using_the_apps_script_api_in_your_app) docs you can find more information about how to use Apps Script on your app, and [here](https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/getting-started#enabling_apis) you can learn how to activate any API (included Apps Scripts API).